# Direction fields, differential equations, and solution in one graph

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, maxima

Assume that I have the following differential equation:

```
\dot{y} = a*(y-0.5) + b*(y-0.5)^3
```

I am curious to see if one can plot in one diagram the actual differential equation (as given above) with dots for the y's that becomes zero, the direction fields, and the solution of the differential equation. I want to be able to see whether the y's that the differential equation becomes zero are stable or not.

I was using `plotdf` in `wxmaxima`, but I am OK with solutions for `Mathematica` and `Matlab` as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want something like 

`plotdf(a*(y-0.5)+b*(y-0.5)^3, [trajectory_at, t0, y0], [xfun, "any equation you want in string form"]);`

Comment: Without initial conditions or values for a or b, try this: sols = Map[y[t] /. # &, Flatten[FullSimplify[ DSolve[y'[t]==a*(y[t]-1/2)+b*(y[t]-1/2)^3, y[t], t]]]]/.{a->1,b->2,C[1]->4} and then this: Plot[sols, {t, -40, -32}]. With more information this could be improved

Comment: @Bill I understand that what you gave is Mathematica code. I would say that `t` should be from 0 to 1. If we try to solve `a*(y-0.5) + b*(y-0.5)^3 = 0` we get three solutions. What I asked is this. Make a graphs that shows the above mentioned solutions along with direction fields and the actual solution of the differential equation. By doing that, I hope I can check the stability of the three points by graph. I hope I made myself clear. For `a` and `b` I will try different cases.

Comment: @Fred I will try this code in `Maxima`. I was able to do something similar like: `lotdf(a*(y-0.5)+b*(y-0.5)^3, [trajectory_at, t0, y0], [x, 0, 1])`. I will try put as `xfun` the solution of the differential equation and I will see.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. I've had to choose numeric values for a and b and initial conditions...

```
expr: a*(y-0.5) + b*(y-0.5)^3, a=2, b=-2;
solve(expr, y);
map(rhs, %), numer;
simplode(%, ";");
plotdf(expr, [y, -2, 2], [trajectory_at, 0, 0], [xfun, %]);
```

The result is

[image]

First, the expression is solved for y. Then make a list of the right hand sides of the solutions.
Turn the list into a string with semicolons as separators. The solutions in the string are plotted with the `xfun` option; the `trajectory_at` option plots the solution of the differential equation that passes through a chosen point ([0,0], in this case). You can click on additional points to plot additional solutions:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, in working this out I think may have found a bug in the way `xfun`parses its arguments---I'm going to report it to the Maxima team. Notice that I added a `numer` on editing? That works around the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Something interesting you can try in Mathematica:-

[image]

Comment: I am using the student edition for Mathematica. Although I put the code, I get the window without any result.

Comment: See the [EquationTrekker documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/EquationTrekker/tutorial/EquationTrekker.html): "To choose an initial condition, all you have to do is position the cursor and right-click. ...  If you hold the right button down and drag the cursor, the solution will be updated in real time as you drag."

Comment: Much obliged. Good job!